# Use promise for headers in Angular 2 HTTP client wrapper

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, es6-promise

I'm having trouble understanding how to refactor this Angular 2 HTTP wrapper so that my headers are loaded from storage before the request.

I am currently loading up the headers in the constructor, but sometimes then retrieval from storage doesn't complete before the request goes out. So far, I haven't had luck moving the header formation into a promise but still returning the Observable request object. Instead the Promise was returned, which I would have to then() to get to the Observable.

Any guidance is appreciated!

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-angular';


@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {
  headers : Headers;

  constructor(private http: Http) {

    this.headers = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })

    // Add auth token to headers
    let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);

    storage.get("user").then(
      (u) => {
        if(u){
          let user = JSON.parse(u);
          this.headers.append('X-User-Email', user.email);
          this.headers.append('X-User-Token', user.authentication_token);
        }else{
          console.log("User not found in storage.")
        }
      }
    )
  }

  get(url) {
    console.log("GET headers: ", this.headers)

    // I want to add a promise here to load the header data
    // from storage before sending this request.  I still
    // want to return this same Observable http request.

    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: this.headers
    })
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's my attempt, which returns `'Promise<Observable<Response>>'` instead of `Observable`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Storage, SqlStorage } from 'ionic-angular';

/*
  A custom wrapper to include headers for API authentication.
  Header info is stored in local storage.
*/

@Injectable()
export class HttpClient {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  buildHeaders(){
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    })
    let storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);

    return storage.get("user").then(
      (u) => {
        if(u){
          let user = JSON.parse(u);
          headers.append('X-User-Email', user.email);
          headers.append('X-User-Token', user.authentication_token);
          return headers;
        }
      }
    )
  }

  get(url) {
    return this.buildHeaders().then(
      (headers) => {
        return this.http.get(url, {
          headers: headers
        })
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the caller receiving the error:

```
this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/confirm_auth_token")
.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data)
)
```

Which results in:

```
Error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<Response>>'.
```

How can I "unwrap" that promise within the get() method of the HttpClient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `HttpClient.get` function is returning a `Promise`, so you need a `then` to access the `Observable<Response>` when the `Promise` resolves:

```
this.http
    .get("http://localhost:3000/confirm_auth_token")
    .then((observable) => {
        observable.subscribe((response) => { console.log(response.text()); }); // or response.json() or whatever
    });
```

If you want to return an `Observable` from your `get` function, you can rearrange things like this:

```
get(url) {
    return Observable
        .fromPromise(this.buildHeaders())
        .switchMap((headers) => this.http.get(url, { headers: headers }));
}
```

Your `get` call would then be something like this:

```
this.http
    .get("http://localhost:3000/confirm_auth_token")
    .subscribe(response => { console.log(response.text()); }); // or response.json() or whatever
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I am hoping to return an Observable, so it is the same functionality as the Angular HTTP object...  Is that doable?

Comment: @cartant one noob question , why you calling get(url)  like this.http.get(url)  and not like <someclass>.get(url)  or this.get(url)  ?  is that http same as Http from @angular/http ? btw , this saved my life

Comment: @SumeetDarade The OP calls it like that because it's an injected instance of his `HttpClient` - so, no, it's not the same `Http` from `@angular/http` (he's used that inside his service).